# Every time the runserver Reload why this warning Shows up in my Terminal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Every time I make changes in the code when runserver is automatically reloaded it shows the below warning. And it's in all my projects.

I'm using Postgres as database.

```
/Users/chip/Documents/Git/test_project/cart/api/v1/serializers.py changed, reloading.
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chip/Documents/Git/apis_gifola/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 780, in writeout_cache
    self._writeout_input_cache(conn)
  File "/Users/chip/Documents/Git/apis_gifola/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 763, in _writeout_input_cache
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO history VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 123145399545856 and this is thread id 4726091200.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 28, 2020 - 05:53:02
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'test_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: I suppose just clear the ipython history will avoid the error message

Comment: thanks @Razenstein but can u please tell me why does it show up some time...??

Comment: No sorry, not that deep into it. I have seen it being discussed also on github  ... ipython ... issues somewhere.

Comment: kkk @Razenstein thanks...